# NodeJS sending MYSQL array data to ejs does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am a newbie to stackoverflow. I will try stick to the guide as possible. Please understand my english as I am not a native speaker.

I am currently using expressJS and ejs to build a chart.

What I am trying to do is,
I retrieve whole data from mysql using query, then send the retrieved data as object to ejs and use that object to display a chart.

Here is the server side code app.js. Here I retrieve whole rows of the query and send the object named as data (first query).

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var mysql = require('mysql');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("connected to the server");
});

app.get("/test",function(request,response){
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({ 
    host : '', //I have blinded personal info here
    user : '',
    password : '',
    database : '',
    port : '',
    multipleStatements: true
  });
  connection.connect(function(err){
    if(!err) {
      console.log("Database is connected ... \n\n");
    } else {
      console.log("Error connecting database ... \n\n");
    }
  });

  var queryS= 'SELECT active_program, SUM(activated_time) AS sumTime\
               FROM program_detail_logs\                
               GROUP BY active_program\
               ORDER BY sumTime DESC; SELECT created_at FROM program_detail_logs';

  connection.query(queryS, function(err, rows, fields) {
   if (!err){                      
      response.render('test', {data: rows[0], data2: rows[1]});
   }
   else{
     console.log('Error while performing Query.');
   }
   connection.end();
   });
});
```

Here is test.ejs, code for making the chart.

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas> //html part, where chart goes

<script>
var progName = [];
progName = <%=data.active_program%>

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
    labels: progName,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Usage time',
        data: [1000, 2000],
        backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
    },
    options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero:true
        }
        }]
    }
    }
});
</script>
```

In order to use the values, I have passed from app.js as the labels of the chart, 
I have declared an array called progNames and put values of the elements of object called active_programs(attribute of MySQL table), which I have assigned as data.active_programs. 
However, this does not seem to work.

To check that the values are properly passed from app.js, I have checked that value of `<%=data[0].active_program=%>` prints out well. However when I print
`<%=data%>`, following is printed: 
`[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]...` so on.

Why is this the case? 
How do I return the array of values from MySQL and assign the same array to the labels(this applies same to the data part) part of the chart?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can You post what data you are sending

Comment: @nikhil it is just string type data, the attribute is called active_program. They are just name of programs

Comment: `[object Object]` this defines you are getting arrays

Comment: Could you show an example of the data object ?, in your file, you assign `progName = data.active_program`, then you said  `<%=data[0].active_program=%>` prints well , is `active_program` an attribute of the data object ?

Comment: @Hamza yes, active_program is the name of the data object, also the attribute of the table in database. One example of the value of the attribute is chrome. I guess `progName = <%=data.active_program%>` is the problem here. ejs cannot directly assign into the progName array

Comment: @hyuklee add this before you assign to the `progName` variable, `<%=JSON.stringify(data.active_program)=%>` to see what value is passed to the ejs file.

Comment: @Hamza just tried, does't seem to pass any values there.

Comment: @hyuklee can you `console.log(rows[0])` in the server to see the structure of the `data` object ?

Comment: @Hamza it looks like this: [RowDataPacket { active_program: 'chrome', sumTime: 227941319 }, ...so on]